# UV-Packer add on

Tags: uv, add-on

I have an issue with installing the UV-Packer addon, I have installed add on to blender but the exe file that should be copied to the UV-Packer folder is an issue, I can't find that folder and it is not created as I install the addon anytime.

Comment: It seems quite well detailed [on the addon's website](https://www.uv-packer.com/blender/). At which point exactly do you miss something?

Comment: Hi :). You can just copy/paste the filepath into the explorer window `C:\Users\JM\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\UV-Packer`. Windows by default hides the AppData system folder